# Compactar e descompactar arquivo em memoria

Tags: python

Tenho algumas varias funções que leem o arquivo direto de um `cache path`, porem eventualmente isso vai custar muito espaço no `filesystem`, existe alguma maneira de gerar esse arquivo em memoria e já salvar ele zipado no disco?

Comment: O que queres é colocar o ficheiro num zip? Não percebo bem o que queres para resolver "isso vai custar muito espaço no filesystem"

Comment: Exatamente ao salvar, já salvar em zip. pensei o seguinte, salvando o arquivo na memoria e depois zippar, é melhor do que salvar o arquivo em disco, zipar, e depois excluir o arquivo que não está zipado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem se percebi bem podes fazer o seguinte:

```
from zipfile import *
import os

zip_name = 'my_zip.zip' # caminho para o zip
file_to_zip = 'file.txt' # caminho para o ficheiro a inserir no zip

if(not os.path.isfile(file_to_zip)):
    print('ficheiro {} nao existe, operacao cancelada'.format(file_to_zip))
else:
    with ZipFile(zip_name, 'w') as myzip: # criar um zip
        try:
            myzip.write(file_to_zip) # inserir ficheiro no zip
            os.remove(file_to_zip) # apagar ficheiro
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        else:
            print('Execucao bem sucedida, {} zipado em {}'.format(file_to_zip, zip_name))
```

Eu faço algumas verificações que considero importantes, `if(not os.path.isfile(file_to_zip))` vai ser para garantirmos que existe ficheiro novo a zipar, porque se não existir não queremos apagar o conetudo do zip anterior (`with ZipFile(zip_name, 'w')`), `os.remove(file_to_zip)` aqui apagamos o ficheiro antigo